# Property injection in to Web Api controller using Autofac

Tags: asp.net-web-api, autofac

I'm trying to set a property on an `System.Web.Http.ApiController` to a value of a resolved `IServerPackageRepository`. The controller runs in a `HttpSelfHostServer` and the `DependencyResolver` has been set to `AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver`. Here is the code from the `Autofac.Module.Load` method

```
...

builder.RegisterType<ServerPackageRepository>()
    .As<IServerPackageRepository>()
    .SingleInstance()
    .WithParameter("path", this.StoragePath);

builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
    .PropertiesAutowired();
```

The `ApiController` controller itself has a property of type

```
public IServerPackageRepository Repository { get; set; }
```

but is never resolved.

I am trying to do it this way because `ApiController` won't take nothing but default constructors. Any suggestions on how to do this the correct way using Autofac?

Comment: what is implementation of `RegisterApiControllers()`?

Comment: @Aliostad `RegisterApiControllers()` is an extension method found in `Autofac.Integration.WebApi` from the Autofac contrib projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `ApiController` is only using the default constructor is sounds like the dependency resolver is not being called and may not be registered with Web API correctly. Here is a working example of self-hosting with constructor injection.

The dependency (in this case a simple logger):

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void Log(string text);
}

public class Logger : ILogger
{
    public void Log(string text)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

A simple controller with a dependency on the logger:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    readonly ILogger _logger;

    public ValuesController(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        _logger.Log("GET api/values");

        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

The console application:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:8080");

        configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // Register API controllers using assembly scanning.
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        // Register API controller dependencies.
        builder.Register<ILogger>(c => new Logger()).SingleInstance();

        var container = builder.Build();

        // Set the dependency resolver implementation.
        var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;

        // Open the HTTP server and listen for requests.
        using (var server = new HttpSelfHostServer(configuration))
        {
            server.OpenAsync().Wait();

            Console.WriteLine("Hosting at http://localhost:8080/{controller}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Hit the controller action using:

`http://localhost:8080/api/values`

Please test this out and let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: I just did the same, except I got 2 Modules: one for the Logger if you will from your example and another for initializing the host. All works fine just as advertised. It's pretty much the same setup I have going on in the main app which is far more involved. So as usual, the blame falls on me shoulders and I am off to debug & test some more. Thanks Alex and @tugberk for your time and efforts. I'll give this one to Alex for providing a full working example.

Comment: so the issue I had was that I did some `HttpSelfHostConfiguration` in one `Autofac.Module`, the `HttpSelfHostServer` in another, taking a dependency on the configuration, and finally, after building the container in the main method, set the `DependencyResolver`. Reordering a few lines took care of my initial problem. Question now is, ideally I'd like to entirely configure the host in a `Module` but can't as `AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver` takes a dependency on the container. Any suggestion how to get round this?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you want but you can create your own base controller and inject the `IServerPackageRepository` into it.

```
public class MyApiController : ApiController { 

    public IServerPackageRepository ServerPackageRepository { get; set; }

    public MyApiController(IServerPackageRepository serverPackageRepository) { 

        ServerPackageRepository = serverPackageRepository;
    }
}
```

Then, use this as your base controller:

```
public class ProductsController : MyApiController { 

    public ProductsController(IServerPackageRepository serverPackageRepository) 
        : base(serverPackageRepository) { 
    }

    public IEnumerable<Product> Get() { 

        ServerPackageRepository.DoWork();

        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any reason why not. I will anyway end up with my own base controller. I was just wondering if that is the best way or only way to achieve this? Elsewhere on blogs documenting the usage of the Autofac Web Api extensions, I read that I don't need a base controller. Alas, I cannot get constructor or property injections working in any `ApiController`.

Comment: Either way, I can't get this running as Autofac won't work its injection magic on properties or constructors of any `ApiController`. All I get is the usual exception that the controller probably doesn't have an empty default ctor. I did register my types as I'd usually do. I did set the DependencyResolver to that of `AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver`. Is there anything else I need to configure to get this working?

Comment: @KarlO weird. I bet that you have a bug somewhere in your code. Are you sure that your controllers are under `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`?

Comment: Yes, absolutely sure. `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` or `typeof(PackagesController).Assembly` makes no difference.

Comment: @KarlO. Alex Meyer-Gleaves has provided a full example in his answer. I think it will help you to see what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to directly wire your dependency to the property like so:

```
var repo = new ServerPackageRepository(path: this.StoragePath);

builder.RegisterInstance(repo)
    .SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
    .WithProperty("Repository", repo)
    .PropertiesAutowired();
```